# Access ngRepeat scope

Tags: angularjs

I want to clear a text box property attached to the ngRepeat scope when the user clicks a sibling button. How would you do this?

ngRepeat does not seem to expose its scope.. otherwise I would pass that addCustomCheckbox function.

**Partial**

```
<div ng-repeat="template in currentUser.templates">

        <div class="form-group">
            <h4>Custom Checkboxes</h4>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li ng-repeat="cc in template.customCheckboxes" class="list-group-item">{{cc}}</li>
            </ul>
            <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomCheckboxName"/>
            <button ng-click="addCustomCheckbox(template,newCustomCheckboxName)" class="btn btn-primary">Add Checkbox</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.addCustomCheckbox = function(template,checkboxName){
    if(checkboxName==="") return;

    if(_.find(template.customCheckboxes,checkboxName)===undefined){
        template.customCheckboxes.push(checkboxName);
        //todo: clear ngRepeatScope newCustomCheckboxName here.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing your thinking.  Don't think of how you can access the scope in the ng-repeat, instead think of how you can move the data you want to access out to *your* scope.

Let's say your $scope, which contains this ng-repeat, has a $scope property called 'model' ($scope.model).  Then, we can set your input model(s) on that $scope.model object instead of leaving it on an object inside the ng-repeat scope.

My example assumes that 'cc' is unique for each iteration.

```
<div ng-repeat="template in currentUser.templates">

        <div class="form-group">
            <h4>Custom Checkboxes</h4>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li ng-repeat="cc in template.customCheckboxes" class="list-group-item">{{cc}}</li>
            </ul>
            <input type="text" ng-model="model[cc]"/>
            <button ng-click="addCustomCheckbox(template,cc)" class="btn btn-primary">Add Checkbox</button>
        </div>
</div>

$scope.addCustomCheckbox = function(template,cc){
    var data = $scope.model[cc];
    if(data==="") return;

    if(_.find(template.customCheckboxes,data)===undefined){
        template.customCheckboxes.push(data);
        $scope.model[cc] = "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Good idea. I ended up using the identity of "template" as a key on the  model lookup because in my example custom checkboxes are in scopes one level below the button... so ng-model="model[template._id]" did the trick.